# How does foursquare's nearby friends functionality work?

Tags: foursquare

I'm working on a location rating functionality that uses the foursquare API, and would like my result to be based on the user's current region. The same way Foursquare divides users in the nearby friends. Does Foursquare use a certain radius based on your location? And if they are, what radius is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foursquare considers a friend to be in the "same city" as you if the friend is within 40 kilometers.